# Как задержать выполнение определеного участка кода

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как задержать выполнение определеного участка кода

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Каталог+</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tablewrapper">
        <div id="tableheader">
            <div class="search">
                <select id="columns" onchange="sorter.search('query')"></select>
                <input type="text" id="query" onkeyup="sorter.search('query')" />
            </div>
            <span class="details">
                <div>Records <span id="startrecord"></span>-<span id="endrecord"></span> of <span id="totalrecords"></span></div>
                <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">reset</a></div>
            </span>
        </div>






        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tinytable">

            <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>Код згідно з НК 004</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Позначення НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Назва НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>чинність НД в Україні</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Кількість сторінок в НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Наявність змін та поправок до НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Позначнення НД який замінено</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Наказ про прийняття НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Скасування</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Мова</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Метод прийняття</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Технічний комітет</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>Познака директиви</h3></th>
                        
                    </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","work2");
                    $db->set_charset("utf8");
                    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM katalog Limit 1000");
                    $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                    if ($_r > 0)

                    {
                        while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                        {
                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[0].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[1].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[5].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[7].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[16].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[12].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[20].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[18].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[21].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[14].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[15].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[13].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[4].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                            
                            ';
                            
                            
                        }                       
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                    }
            goto a;
?>
```

Задержать вот эту часть кода  секунд на 20-30

```
 <?php 

                            $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","work2");
                            $db->set_charset("utf8");
                            $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM katalog Limit 1000, 1000");
                            $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                            if ($_r > 0)
    
                            {
                                while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                                {
                                    echo '
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[0].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[1].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[5].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[7].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[16].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[12].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[20].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[18].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                              <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[21].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[14].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[15].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[13].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                             <td>
                                                <a>'.$tablerows[4].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    
                                    
                                    ';
                                    
                                    
                                }                       
                                
                            }else{
                                echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                            };
                    a:;
                    ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Но что бы дальше прогружалось вот эта часть кода:

```
 <div id="tablefooter">
              <div id="tablenav">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                        <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                        <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                        <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select id="pagedropdown"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tablelocation">
                    <div>
                        <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                        </select>
                        <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="totalpages"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
            headclass:'head',
            ascclass:'asc',
            descclass:'desc',
            evenclass:'evenrow',
            oddclass:'oddrow',
            evenselclass:'evenselected',
            oddselclass:'oddselected',
            paginate:true,
            size:10,
            colddid:'columns',
            currentid:'currentpage',
            totalid:'totalpages',
            startingrecid:'startrecord',
            endingrecid:'endrecord',
            totalrecid:'totalrecords',
            hoverid:'selectedrow',
            pageddid:'pagedropdown',
            navid:'tablenav',
    
            init:true
        });
      </script>
    
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Пробовал через `goto();` Но не понимаю как после вернуться к той части скрипта которую приостановил

Comment: С goto Вы не сможете вернуться обратно, если специально не сделаете для этого соответствующие условия (другую метку например), в этом то и весь смысл прыжка, перейти не возвращаясь и в пределах одной функции или одного документа, если это вынесено в общий код (но с возможностью прыгать между условными блоками в чем и есть основная мощь) Попробуйте fastcgi_finish_request в php

Comment: @noname2019 , когда я создаю другой параметр допустим `goto(b);` и вставляю его ниже той части которая должна прогрузится `<?php goto b; ?>` таким способом ,то данные которые должны были подгрузится перестают быть частью таблици, в которую я  хочу сделать постепенную догрузку данных

Comment: Вы не реализуете то что задумали с goto) Danny в ответе правильно подметил, без фронта в этом случаи не обойтись, с стороны сервера постепенной подгрузки данных не может быть, если только не реализована соответствующая логика и т.д (допустим websocket и т.п.) в случаи обычного соединения запрос-ответ, нельзя задержать часть ответа и отдать его позднее, только разве что запросить его отдельно после загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. goto не используйте, это плохая вещь во всех языках высокого уровня, в число которых входит php.
2. Казалось бы, можно использовать sleep:

```
sleep ( int $seconds ) : int 
// Откладывает исполнение программы на число секунд, указанное в параметре seconds.
```

НО!

Если вы используете sleep, то пользователь увидит весь текст с задержкой. И то, что вы хотели сначала показать, и то, что потом. Поэтому

3. на самом деле ваша задача решается не на стороне сервера при помощи php, а на фронте при помощи javascript.

Comment: Извините за прямоту, но насчет goto не соглашусь. Это плохая вещь в неумелых руках, было бы это настолько плохо как Вы назвали, его бы не внедряли в php, не просто каким-то экстеншеном, а с коробки. Иногда он спасает от написания кучи ненужного кода. И сомневаюсь что его не депрекейтят по историческим причинам...

Comment: @Danny, используя `sleep ( int $seconds ) : int ` перестает выполняться та часть кода которая ниже полностью

Comment: КоТАК, для вывода части текста с задержкой лучше использовать javascript `setTimeout()`.